# AspNetMVC4 installation in Windows Docker container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-for-windows

Dear members of Server fault.

I am trying to to setup a windows core container (2016) to run an ASP .NET 4.6 web application, one of the prerequites is [AsPNetMVC4Setup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) installation.

On regular windows machine this can easily installed from the user interface, however on the container this being an `.exe` file i am unable to use `msiexec` or couldnt find a `/q` way of installing the dependency.

I have no options to install using `choco` or `nuget` because the cluster is behind a enterprise firewall and there is no nuget setup.

Is there any way to install the exe file using cli or offline nuget installation. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and below it is, the *exe* supports `/q` which would perform silent install, however there is no stdout on the container, you can start-process in *powershell* and then wait. I would recommend verifing the installation here

```
AsPNetMVC4Setup.exe /q

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft ASP .NET\
```